# Objective C - Executing async operations serially in a queue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

Currently I've implemented a class that wraps an NSOperationQueue and holds a pointer to the previous operation. Every time I add another operation to the queue I add the previous operation as a dependency because the operations are writing to the same file (and the calls should execute in order, I just need those operations off of the main thread). The current implementation looks something like this...

```
@interface FileStoreOperationQueue : NSOperationQueue

-(void)createPayloadOperation(NSString* payload);

@property(nonatomic, weak) FileStoreOperation* previousOperation;

@end


@implementation FileStoreOperationQueue

-(void)createPayloadOperation(NSString* payload){
    // Create a new FileStoreOperation

    // Add the 'previousOperation' as a dependency 

    // Add new operation to self

    // previous operation = newOperation
}

@end
```

This feels a bit hacky, is there a more natural and clean way to do this with the API?

Comment: Are your tasks _asynchronous_ or _synchronous_? This matters much, since in the second case (synchronous tasks) there is a very simple and straight forward solution. If the tasks are inherently _asynchronous_ though, the solutions become more involved. However, the solution with NSOperationQueues and NSOperations is the most elaborate and complex. ;)

Comment: did you get it working? I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the number of concurrent operations for the queue to 1, effectively making the queue a serial queue. The docs warn that you shouldn't rely on the operations being executed in order because changes in the readiness of an operation can change the execution order, but if all your operations remain ready to execute you should be fine.

See [`-setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_15) as well as the section *Additional Operation Queue Behaviors*.

Another option is to drop down a level and use Grand Central Dispatch's serial queues instead of `NSOperationQueue`. This would require that you convert your operations to blocks, but you can bank on your blocks being executed one at a time and in order.

Finally, you could create your own subclass of `NSOperationQueue` that automatically makes each new operation dependent on the previous one. It's the same solution you're using now, except the queue can keep track of the previous operation and adding the dependency, so it should feel cleaner and not so "hacky."

Answer (score 0):

From the [NSOperation documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591):

> Dependencies are a convenient way to execute operations in a specific
>   order. You can add and remove dependencies for an operation using the
>   addDependency: and removeDependency: methods. By default, an operation
>   object that has dependencies is not considered ready until all of its
>   dependent operation objects have finished executing. Once the last
>   dependent operation finishes, however, the operation object becomes
>   ready and able to execute.

```
[operation addDependency: previousOperation];
```